# Django. Pass an array to a child template via include tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create an array on the fly and pass it to a child template:

`{% include "template.html" with foo = ['one', 'two'] %}`

but this doesn't work. Does anybody know how to generate an array in parent template and then pass it to another template?

Comment: what about `foo='one,two'` and split inside template ?

Comment: L_S, yes, thank you, it works great: `load split` `foo='one','two'|split`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do like

```
{% include "template.html" with foo = 'one,two' %}
```

and use `split`